# react native image not show on android emulator

Tags: react-native

below is my code

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#f1f5f7", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <ScrollView>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://mosfeed.id/assets/collections/ads/small/photo_2021-03-10%2016.38.26.jpeg",
          }}
          style={{
            width: screenWidth,
            height: 190,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            paddingHorizontal: 50,
          }}
        ></ImageBackground>
        <ItemData title="Upcoming Events" data={DATA1} />
        <ItemData title="Premium" data={DATA2} />
      </ScrollView>
      <MaterialSnackbar ref={snackbarRef} />
    </View>
```

the problem is that the image not showing on android emulator only and only from my server. but when i change the link from other server link the image show.

is there any setting so the image can be showed on my server.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i achieved this by:

```js
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

<ImageBackground style={ styles.imgBackground } 
                 resizeMode='cover' 
                 source={require('./Your/Path.png')}>

   //place your now nested component JSX code here

</ImageBackground>
```

And then the Styles:

```js
imgBackground: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1 
},
```